# SQL: Update multiple rows

Tags: mysql, select, syntax

I want to update multiple rows with one query. I am using MySQL.

What is the correct query?

Here is an example where I need to update multiple last names with one query.

Start:

```
name      last_name
______    ________
James     abcasd
Becky     hadsfd
Richard   adfdfadgg
```

Finish:

```
name      last_name
______    ________
James     Jamerson
Becky     Beckerdude
Richard   O'Nerdy
```

Comment: Where are you going to get the new values?  Another table?

Answer (score 3):

if are limited cases, can use `Case Statement.`

```
update yourTable set Last_Name = CASE When Name = 'James' then 'Jamerson'
                                 WHEN Name = 'Becky' then 'Beckerdude'..
                                 --then for each case
                                 END
```

**edit**

if you got the relation Name - NewLastName in another table, then create a script:

```
select
'When Name = '''+CAST(Name as Varchar(50)+''' Then '''+Cast(LastName as Varchar(50)+'''
from yourTableWithRelation
```

this will generate all `When Name then LastName`
then add  it to the `update`

```
Update yourTable set Last_Name = CASE 
--Paste here the generated
END
```

**edit2**

another *BEST* way to `update`, if you got the relation in another table:

```
Update T set T.Last_Name = T2.LastName from YourTableToUpdate T inner join TableWithNewLastName T2 
on T1.Name = T2.Name
```

Comment: unfortunately there will be about 2,000 rows, I could make a script to produce the SQL, but looking for alternatives first :)

Comment: Well, but mySQL is not magic. You have to specify for each name which one will be the new name. Do you got the relation Name-NewLastName in another table ? you can create a litle select that will create you the update

Comment: Edit2 sounds like the best and most elegant to me, but I have a weird prejudice against scripting in SQL. In any case, thanks for the answer. It's useful to know that this is possible!

Comment: if you got the relation in another table, edit2 is the best you can do.